# Error while loading parquet format file into Amazon Redshift using copy command and manifest file

Tags: amazon-redshift, parquet

I'm trying to load parquet file using manifest file and getting below error.

query:     124138ailed due to an internal error. File 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/sbredshift-east/data/000002_0  has an invalid version number: )

Here is my copy command

**copy testtable from 's3://sbredshift-east/manifest/supplier.manifest'
IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/MyRedshiftRole123'
FORMAT AS PARQUET
manifest;**

here is my manifest file

```
**{  
   "entries":[  
      {  
         "url":"s3://sbredshift-east/data/000002_0",
         "mandatory":true,
         "meta":{  
            "content_length":1000
         }
      }
   ]
}**
```

I'm able to load the same file using copy command by specifying the file name.

**copy testtable from 's3://sbredshift-east/data/000002_0'                                                                                                                                                            IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/MyRedshiftRole123'                                                                                                                                                                      FORMAT AS PARQUET;**

INFO:  Load into table 'supplier' completed, 800000 record(s) loaded successfully.
COPY

What could be wrong in my copy statement?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Please let us know solution if you fins one. I dont see proper documentation from AWS regarding loading of parquet file with manifest

Comment: I couldn't get this to work with parquet files UNLOADed with MANIFEST VERBOSE, trying all the suggested "content" and "meta" property permutations.  My solution was to reUNLOAD as CSV without manifest.  My objective was to change datatype of primary key column.  The elapsed time and data footprint differences were negligible, but I have at this time under 20GB data across 50-60 tables, max rows 54 million.

Answer (score 1):

This error happens when the content_length value is wrong. You have to specify the correct **content_length**. You could check it executing an **s3 ls** command.

```
aws s3 ls s3://sbredshift-east/data/
2019-12-27 11:15:19        539 sbredshift-east/data/000002_0
```

The 539 (file size) should be the same than the content_lenght value in your manifest file.

I don't know why they are using this meta value when you don't need it in the direct copy command.

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've gotten parquet copy to work with manifest file is to add the meta key with the content_length.

From what I can gather in my error logs, the COPY command for parquet (w/ manifest) might first be reading the files using Redshift Spectrum as an external table. If that's the case, this hidden step does require the content_step which contradicts their initial statement about COPY commands.

https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/redshift/latest/dg/loading-data-files-using-manifest.html