# Redshift copy from Parquet manifest in S3 fails and says MANIFEST parameter requires full path of an S3 object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I'm using Firehose to put records in Parquet format in an S3 bucket. I've manually defined a glue table.

So I've got a manifest like

```
{
  "entries": [
    {"url":"s3://my-bucket/file1.parquet"},
    {"url":"s3://my-bucket/file2.parquet"}
  ]
}
```

And a copy command like

```
COPY schema_name.table_name
FROM 's3://my-bucket/manifest.json'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_iam_role=arn:aws:iam::123456:role/RoleWithPermissionToRedshiftAndBucket'
PARQUET
MANIFEST;
```

And it gives this mysterious error that has 0 results on Google.

```
[XX000][500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: COPY with MANIFEST parameter requires full path of an S3 object.
Details:
-----------------------------------------------
error:  COPY with MANIFEST parameter requires full path of an S3 object.
code:      8001
context:
query:     23514459
location:  scan_range_manager.cpp:795
process:   padbmaster [pid=108497]
-----------------------------------------------;
```

It seems to me that I am definitely specifying the full path, so I'm not sure what's up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that was wrong was that the bucket was in a different region, which would also prevent it from working.

One reason you might get this error message is if the bucket is in another aws account.

But what actually fixed it for me was adding content_length to the manifest, since it is required for parquet.

```
{
  "entries": [
    {
      "url":"s3://my-bucket/file1.parquet",
      "mandatory":true,
      "meta":{
        "content_length":2893394
      }
    },
    {
      "url":"s3://my-bucket/file2.parquet",
      "mandatory":true,
      "meta":{
        "content_length":2883626
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Apparently, if you leave content_length out, you'll get an unrelated error message. This guy made the same mistake and got an error message saying

```
File has an invalid version number
```

[Error while loading parquet format file into Amazon Redshift using copy command and manifest file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56944036/error-while-loading-parquet-format-file-into-amazon-redshift-using-copy-command)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the correct CREDENTIALS or IAM_ROLE set.

I fixed this exact same error
`COPY with MANIFEST parameter requires full path of an S3 object` by changing my  IAM_ROLE - from one that didn't have permissions to load to this table.

(Redshift error messages in this area are no good).

Comment: Had the same issue and this was the solution. The error msg given by Redshift is less then useless in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and I had mistyping S3 instead s3. Check if there is something wrong in the s3 address.

COPY users_data
FROM 's3://users-data-283794720301'
IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::283794720301:role/RedshiftS3'
FORMAT AS PARQUET;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).